# Using AWS Cognito and AWS Lambda to authenticate users

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

What is the point of these two calls/functions:

```
- (AWSTask *)refresh
```

and

```
- (AWSTask *)getIdentityId
```

if you want to use ASW Lambda as a backend? (like so: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/getting-started-lambda.html)

Do you need the functions above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing using [LambdaAuth](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) to sign up and sign in users with calling Lambda from your mobile app.  You do not need to use LambdaAuth to be able to call Lambda from your mobile app.  If you need to sign up and sign in users, you may want to try [Cognito Your User Pools](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxGNH1AUKDRZDH/Announcing-Your-User-Pools-in-Amazon-Cognito) which may be easier to integrate than LambdaAuth and doesn't require you to implement the refresh and getIdentityId methods.

Comment: so i see x^x ways and languages to connect and create a good auth with aws. Still curious what is the role of refresh and getIdentityId if I am NOT using Lambda or Cognito User Pools?

Comment: You need to implement refresh and getIdentityId if you are using Developer Authenticated Identities with Cognito Identity.  Developer Authenticated Identities allows you to authenticate with an arbitrary backend that we don't natively support i.e. Apple's Gamecenter. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Comment: Can you use AWS Lambda instead to roll your own developer identy auth? Like this https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth